# PHP: Returning function value by itself not working

Tags: php

I have a function inside of a class, every time I use I got error undefined function `in_array_r()` inside of foreach. But when I use it outside of the class as normal function it works. I want to use this inside of the class so I will not call in every page.

```
public function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
        foreach ($haystack as $item) {
            if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is recursive - it's calling itself. When you put it inside a class (as a method), you need to update the reference to `in_array_r()` within the method body.

This:

```
. . .(is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, . . .
```

Becomes:

```
. . .(is_array($item) && $this->in_array_r($needle, . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the method to the object.

```
$this->in_array_r();
```

Comment: also you can improve your code and return false if $haystack false, as a simple check.